# Power interaction method ,to find the latest eigen Value and vector?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

Briefly write the algorithm  of power iteration method to find the largest eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix using following normalization .

Vn = V/√(V .V)        ( Vn = normalized eigenvector)

Answer (score 1):

```py
'''
Findung highest eigenvector and eigenvalue of a real symmetric matrix
'''

import numpy as np

def eigen_vect_and_value(A, u_initial, step, accuracy):
    u = u_initial
    u = u / np.sqrt(u.dot(u))
    while True:
        Au = A.dot(u) 
        k = u.dot( Au )
        Au_ku = Au - k*u
        if Au_ku.dot(Au_ku) < accuracy**2:
            return u, k
        u = u + step * Au_ku
        u = u / np.sqrt(u.dot(u))


'''
2D test:
'''


'''
Rotation Matrix Generation, given angle 
'''
def U(angle):
    cos_ = np.cos(angle)
    sin_ = np.sin(angle)
    return np.array([[cos_, -sin_],
                     [sin_,  cos_]])

'''
Egienvalue Diagonal Matrix Generation, given eigenvalues
'''
def D(k):
    return np.diag(k)


'''
Symmetric Matrix SymMtrx generation, 
with eigenvector matrix W
and diagonal egienvalue matrix D(k) 
'''

def Make_2D_Sym_Mtrx(angle, egenvalues):
    W = U(angle)
    return W.dot( D(egenvalues).dot(W.T) ), W

'''
Test input:
'''
rot_angle = np.pi/7
egenvalue_max = 3
egenvalue_min = 0.8
step = 0.3
accuracy = 5e-10


'''
Creating a 2D test symmetric matrix and egienvector matrix
'''
k = np.array([egenvalue_max, egenvalue_min])
SymMtrx, W = Make_2D_Sym_Mtrx(rot_angle, k)

'''
Applying iterative algorithm on the 2D test symmetric matrix
'''
u_max, k_max = eigen_vect_and_value(SymMtrx, np.array([1,0]), step, accuracy)


print('calculated egienvalue')
print(k_max)
print('')
print('actual eigenvalue')
print(k[0])
print('')
print('calculated eigenvector')
print(u_max)
print('')
print('actual eigenvector')
print(W[:,0])
print('')
print('error')
print(min(np.linalg.norm(W[:,0] - u_max), np.linalg.norm(W[:,0] + u_max)))
```

Comment: Why did you use `np.array([1,0])` as `u_initial`?

Comment: @brethvoice Yeah, it is a choice that is compatible with the example. There is nothing special about it, I just knew it worked a priori. First, I create the symmetric matrix to be diagonal with highest eigenvalue along the axis `[1, 0]` and then I rotate it at the not too big angle of `pi/7` so the gradient decent orbit from this initial condition is supposed to converge to the maximal eigenvalue. However, in general, on needs to think about a method for choosing initial conditions for gradient decent.

Comment: @brethvoice I kind of think of this as a applied Morse theory problem. The quadratic function `f(x) = x^t A x` restricted on the unit sphere '|x|^2 = 1' is Morse function and according to the theory, it has a bunch of critical points, which correspond to the egenvectors and the critical values of 'f' correspond to  egenvalues. By Morse theory, the maximal value and the minimal value of `f(x)` have basins of attraction with the topologies of the open disc equal to the dimension of the unit sphere. The rest of the critical points have attractors of measure zero, so very unlikely to come across.